# Antonym for "endorsement"?

Tags: antonyms

What would be an antonym for *endorsement*?  E.g.

> His poor performance and results served as an (*anti-endorsement*) of his technical method.

Comment: [***Indictment***](http://www.onelook.com/?w=indictment&ls=a).

Comment: Or [*condemnation*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/condemnation).

Comment: ... repudiation [[AHDEL](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/repudiate)]

Comment: i'm inclined with `condemnation` as the first choice...

Comment: I think "condemnation" sounds too harsh and I think "indictment" has purely legal connotations for most native speakers. I might write your sentence as: "His poor performance and results served to undermine his technical method."

Comment: @Baz, i was looking for a `noun`

Comment: In certain contexts, the opposite or *endo-* is *exo-* ... So if you want to invent your word, try that.

Comment: You could say that "His poor performance served as a contestation of his technical method"

Answer (score 1):

***disapproval,  criticizing or criticism, reprehension. censure 
disparagement, depreciation, derogation***

[Merriam-Webster's Dictionary of Synonyms: A Dictionary of Discriminated Synonyms with Antonyms and Analogous and Contrasted Words](https://books.google.ca/books?id=8N4UReTJYhUC&pg=PA56&dq=endorsement%20antonyms&hl=en&sa=X&ei=KCQsVeGOJOWIsQSk7oGQCQ&ved=0CDIQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=endorsement%20antonyms&f=false)

Answer (score 1):

**Denounce**, or **denouncement**

Webster definition: “to pronounce especially publicly to be blameworthy or evil”

I was about to ask this same question and then the word cane to me.

Answer (score 0):

Nonendorsement springs to mind but I'm not sure if it would be considered an antonym. For example, if you endorse a particular candidate, then there is an automatic nonendorsement of the remaining candidates. This is not a disapproval, indictment or condemnation of the latter.

Having said that, this is not a good sentence:

His poor performance and results served as a nonendorsement of his technical method.

Answer (score 0):

It's a strange omission; endorsement doesn't have an accurate antonym as far as I can work out.

Endorsement has a very specific meaning of a formal statement of recommendation. It does not necessarily imply approval or even liking something. You can endorse something as being objectively good, while simultaneously saying that you personally hate it and find it useless.

There doesn't appear to be any equivalent word for a formal statement of negative recommendation.